# How to change multiple main variables at the same time in Java

Tags: java, methods, scope

In my understanding of Java, the most common ways to set the instance variables of a class object are:

1. foo.setFooStuff(bar); *// put a setter method inside the class*
2. foo = modifyFooStuff(foo, bar); *// pass & return entire object*

Let's say my main() has an object of class bigA, which contains a collection of class littleA objects (which contain instance variables), and another object of class bigB, which contains a collection of class littleB objects (which have different instance variables from littleA). How do I write a method to modify instance variables of one or more littleA and littleB objects at the same time?

(Note: I suspect this is a common question, but I searched and didn't find it. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology.)

Edit: more concrete example: Let's say I'm making Monopoly. A player has money (in various denominations) and properties (some with houses). She wants to upgrade some properties to hotels. Money has to be added and subtracted, as do houses and hotels. I know how to do this in a pass-by-reference language, but not using pass-by-value, unless I make the entire game state into one huge object and pass it around, which seems like a lot of memory shuffling and basically the same as using global variables, which is bad, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you write a method on the bigA/bigB classes that take the value you want to set and then walk the collection of littleA/B objects setting the instance variables as you go. Like:

```
// Assuming Foo has a member collection of smallFoo
Foo A = new Foo();
// do stuff that populates the collection of smallFoo in A
A.setSmallFooZipCode("23444");
```

---

```
public void setSmallFooZipCode(String zip_ {
    // for thisSmallFoo in smallFoo
        thisSmallFoo.setZip(zip);
    // end for
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects (including your container objects) should represent something--thinking of them in terms of A/B makes this a little tough.

On top of that, if you are always modifying an attribute in two classes at once I'd suggest that's a pretty bad code smell...

Off the top of my head I can't think of anything I'd model this way, so it's hard to come up with an example.  Either A and B should be contained in a parent ab class (and that class should have the attribute), or a and b should be the same interface--in either case these would then go into a single collection in a parent container.

So that said, you should have a method on the parent container object that does the work.  In most cases it shouldn't be a method like "setAttribute...", it should be a method like "doAction".  In other words, if your container is a "Herd" and it contains a bunch of Elephants, then you would tell the Herd to move to a certain location and let the Herd object send a message to each elephant telling it where to go.

If  you think of methods in terms of "Asking an object to do something for you" rather than operating on an object, it helps make some of these decisions much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply encapsulate `BigA` and `BigB` in another object:

```
class BigWrapper {
    private BigA bigA;
    private BigB bigB;

    public void someMethod() {
        bigA.someMethod();
        bigB.someMethod();
    }
}
```

`someMethod()` within `BigA` would modify the `LittleA` instances. Same for `BigB`:

```
class BigB {
    private LittleA[] littles;

    public void someMethod() {
        //do something with the littles
    }
}
```

---

Of course, this solution *doesn't allow you to specify which* `Little` *instances to target*, as well as *doesn't allow you to specify which behavior should be performed* (which specific method to invoke via the littles).

If you want that flexibility, use callbacks:

```
interface Little { }
class LittleA implements Little { }
class LittleB implements Little { }

interface Callback<T extends Little> {
    void perform(int currentIndex, T currentLittle);
}

class CallbackHandler<T extends Little> {
    private int[] indexes;
    private Callback<T> callback;

    public CallbackHandler(int[] indexes, Callback<T> callback) {
        this.indexes = indexes;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void perform(T[] littles) {
        for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            int index = indexes[i];
            callback.perform(i, littles[index]);
        }
    }
}

class BigWrapper {
    private BigA bigA;
    private BigB bigB;

    public BigWrapper(BigA bigA, BigB bigB) {
        this.bigA = bigA;
        this.bigB = bigB;
    }

    public void perform(CallbackHandler<LittleA> aCallback, CallbackHandler<LittleB> bCallback) {
        bigA.perform(aCallback);
        bigB.perform(bCallback);
    }
}

class BigA {
    private LittleA[] littles;

    public BigA(LittleA[] littles) {
        this.littles = littles;
    }

    public void perform(CallbackHandler<LittleA> callback) {
        callback.perform(littles);
    }
}

class BigB {
    private LittleB[] littles;

    public BigB(LittleB[] littles) {
        this.littles = littles;
    }

    public void perform(CallbackHandler<LittleB> callback) {
        callback.perform(littles);
    }
}
```

The `CallbackHandler` maps the actual callback to the indexes you want to target.

So you would first create the callback:

```
Callback<LittleA> aCallback = (currentIndex, currentLittle) -> {
    //do what you want to the littles
};
```

Then pass that to a `CallbackHandler`, which allows you to specify the indexes you wish to target:

```
int[] indexes = { 0, 1, 2 };
CallbackHandler<LittleA> aCallbackHandler = new CallbackHandler<>(indexes, aCallback);
```

`BigWrapper` exposes a `perform(CallbackHandler<LittleA>, CallbackHandler<LittleB>)`, so you would pass the handlers to that method.

An MCVE would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LittleA[] littleA = {
        new LittleA(),
        new LittleA(),
        new LittleA()
    };
    LittleB[] littleB = {
        new LittleB(),
        new LittleB(),
        new LittleB()
    };
    BigA bigA = new BigA(littleA);
    BigB bigB = new BigB(littleB);
    BigWrapper big = new BigWrapper(bigA, bigB);

    Callback<LittleA> aCallback = (index, little) -> {
        //...
    };
    Callback<LittleB> bCallback = (index, little) -> {
        //...
    };

    CallbackHandler aCallbackHandler = new CallbackHandler(new int[] { 2, 3, 4 }, aCallback);
    CallbackHandler bCallbackHandler = new CallbackHandler(new int[] { 5, 6, 7 }, bCallback);

    big.perform(aCallbackHandler, bCallbackHandler);
}
```